# Armature rotation error

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm working on animating a teddy bear...
Anyway, I've been following this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkuOs_VA_y4&t=423s) tutorial and I can't quite get it completely right.
The biggest issue I am having is the rotation when trying to pose (in pose mode).
The video shows the rotation in relation to the bone pivot point regardless of where the 3D cursor is positioned. However on mine all rotation is done in relation to the 3d cursor and it is making for some very funky movements and difficult to pose. I have to move the 3D cursor and even then it yeilds funny results.

Any idea what I am missing? Or perhaps there is a step in the tutorial that has been omitted.
Image shows shoulder and ankle rotation[image]

I need to go through the tutorial again, but I need another set of eyes from someone more knowledgeable than I.

Thanks in advance

Blender version 2.81.16 on Windows 10 64 bit.

Edit: I may have figured it out. I was in Layout and should have been in Modeling. Not something mentioned in the video, you just have to catch it as it shows that's the active tab.

Edit 2: Yep. That was it. Now to get my animation following a path with deforming...but that is another topic. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've set your *Tranform Pivot Point* to the *3D Cursor*, I guess it's your problem, switch to *Median Point* for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that as well when I was matching my setup to his. That actually makes more sense now that you explained it.  I had been following other rigify tutorials prior to this and someone said to change it for their method.